# How to cut old commits from a feature branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have `feature2` branch, that was created this way:

```
develop -> feature1(branched from develop) -> feature2(branched from feature1)
```

`feature1` has already merged, Now I'm trying to merge `feature2` branch. But in the commit history and the "changes" tab, I see the changes from the feature1 branch:

```
1. Commit to feature2
2. Commit to feature2
3. Commit to feature1
4. Commit to feature1
```

So, how can I drop everything before second commit? Like if `feature2` branch was branched from `develop`?
It makes review a bit difficult, because I see old code in Changes tab

Comment: Do a 'git rebase'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase `feature2` on to `develop` and drop the commits you do not want:

```
# while on feature2:
git rebase -i develop
```

The interactive rebase will open a text editor allowing you to specify which commits to keep and which to drop:

```
pick Commit 1
pick Commit 2
pick Commit 3
pick Commit 4
```

Comments in the text editor tell you what you can do, but in your case:

```
pick Commit 1
pick Commit 2
drop Commit 3
drop Commit 4
```

If `feature2` has already been pushed, you'll need to force-push the branch:

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

---

**Warning: this will orphan anyone else's branch if they based it on `feature2`. Be careful and talk to your teammates first!**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to drop anything. Git is smart enough to know that those commits for feature1 have already been merged to master, and won't try to merge them again when you merge the feature2 branch.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But i can't review new commits. Gitlab changes tab has information about previous feature code, so I can't see only new one

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't realise this was a gitlab specific question. I don't use gitlab. It sounds like you want to rebase feature2 against master before review.